# Long multiline equations adding white space beforehand when placed on a page break

Tags: equations, page-breaking, memoir

I have a little problem getting long multiline equations to work over a page break in the memoir class. If the equation is by any chance at a page break, the equations will get placed on the next page but in the text before that equation, a lot of white spaces are added. Also, I get an underful vbox error.

Here is a picture to illustrate my problem:
[image: Visualization of the problem]

And here the tex example code:

---

```
\documentclass[
11pt, a4paper,        
fleqn,               
twoside, openright,   
final          
]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Input-Encoding
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}  % Output-Encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}   % English language package

%Geometry
\usepackage[includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  

\usepackage{blindtext} 


\begin{document}
    \newpage

    \mainmatter
    \OnehalfSpacing

    \chapter{Testchapter}
    \blindtext[6]

    \blindtext[1]

    {\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm} \small
            \begin{gather}
            \label{eq:S1f}
            \begin{aligned}
            y1 &= a+b+c\\ &{} d+e+f \\ &{} g+h+j
            \end{aligned}\\
            \begin{aligned}
            y2 &= a+b+c\\ &{} d+e+f \\ &{} g+h+j
            \end{aligned}\\
            \begin{aligned}
            y3 &= a+b+c\\ &{} d+e+f \\ &{} g+h+j
            \end{aligned}\\
            \begin{aligned}
            y4 &= a+b+c\\ &{} d+e+f \\ &{} g+h+j
            \end{aligned}
            \end{gather}
        }

    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

I am using a gather environment because that was the best way to get my relatively long equations nicely shown in LaTex. I also tried some other variants here already (without improvement).

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? Would be really bad if I had to worry about where to place my equation as this should be the job of Latex :D

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? a) Eq. 1.1 to 1.4. behave as a float or b) pagebreak between eq. 1.3 and 1.4?

Comment: you should never have a blank line before a displayed equation also you probably want `\allowdisplaybreaks` to allow the display to split over a page.

Comment: @leandriis Actually I could live with both, only the white spaces were annoying me, but \allowdisplaybreaks and \raggedbottom seems to solve the problem 
@ David Any particular reason why a blank line before equations should be avoided? I think I have it in most of my text without blank lines, but never really looked for this...

Comment: a blank line before a display will always leave more space above than below the display.  this will be more noticeable before multi-line displays, but is always there.  it will also allow a page break before a display, which is bad style in traditional math publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the directives

```
\allowdisplaybreaks
\raggedbottom
```

to your preamble:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that. That seems to solve it. Was trying many hours on this and the solution is so simple. Thanks :)